# PNP not controlling which LED is on as expected

Tags: transistors, led, circuit-analysis, bjt, pnp

I have a simulated circuit below, where a PNP determines when LED 1 or LED 2 is on or off. I don't understand why LED 2 is on when the PNP is active and LED 1 doesn't turn on but stays off. Is this because when the PNP is active there is less resistance and thus the current flows through LED 2 and not through LED 1? I need help to understand the circuit below.

[image]

Comment: redraw the schematic diagram ... make it vertical ... LEDs side by side ... D1 and Q1 side by side ... R1 above ... then look at the schematic diagram again

Comment: At what LED current does your simulator indicate that the LED is **ON**? For your circuit as shown, neither LED1 nor LED2 should light up (much).

Comment: Led 2 is on, when pnp is active "close"

Comment: Add a current and a voltage meter at node 2 and node 4. Compare the values while q1 is off and on.

Comment: OP's schematic suggests that Q1 has **always** \$\beta=100\$. That's misleading in this case where base is grounded. Q1's collector cannot force current through LED2 when its emitter is somewhere near one volt. Base current is very high (16 to 17 ma), but collector current is tiny - not enough to light up LED2. LTspice verifies this. OP's simulator is bogus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The base current \$I_B\$ will be roughly \$17\text{ mA}\$ in your circuit, most likely putting Q1 into deep saturation, hence \$U_{CE} \approx 0\$. It follows that

$$ U_{10} = U_{D1} + U_{\text{LED}1} \approx U_{\text{LED}2} = U_{\text{LED,Forward}} \,. $$

The upper branch will behave approximately like a diode with forward voltage

$$U_{D1\text{,Forward}} + U_{LED\text{,Forward}} \approx 0.7\text{ V} + U_{\text{LED,Forward}} > U_{\text{LED,Forward}} = U_{10},$$

so there simply is not enough voltage applied to put LED1 and D1 into forward conduction. LED1 stays off.

(Of course, there is going to be some minuscule current flowing through LED1 owing to the exponential diode I/V curve, just not nearly enough to consider it "on".)